# Monad transformer for Future[Either[Error, Option[User]]]

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers

Consider the signature of `retrieveUser` where retrieving a non-existent user is not modelled as an error, that is, it is modelled as `Future[Right[None]]`:

```
def retrieveUser(email: String): Future[Either[Error, Option[User]]]
```

Does there exist a monad transformer `MT` such that we can write

```
(for {
  user <- MT(retrieveUser(oldEmail))
  _    <- MT(updateUser(user.setEmail(newEmail)))
} {}).run
```

Using `EitherT` the best I can do is the following:

```
EitherT(retrieveUser(oldEmail)).flatMap {
  case Some(user) =>
    EitherT(updateUser(user.setEmail(newEmail)))

  case None => 
    EitherT.right(Future.successful({}))
}.run
```

The problem is that mapping over `EitherT(retrieveUser(email))` results in `Option[User]`, instead of unboxed `User`, which breaks the for-comprehension.

Comment: Is it supposed to be Scalaz or Scala-Cats?

Comment: `OptionT(EitherT(retrieveUser(oldEmail))` with `-Ypartial-unification` worked fine in Scalaz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that the order of parameters is the same as in [`EitherT` form Scala Cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/EitherT.html): an `EitherT[F[_], A, B]` is essentially just a wrapper around `F[Either[A, B]]`.

Likewise, [`OptionT[F, A]`](https://typelevel.org/cats/api/cats/data/OptionT.html) is wrapper around `F[Option[A]]`.

Thus,

```
OptionT[EitherT[Future, Error, ?], A]
```

is a wrapper around

```
EitherT[Future, Error, Option[A]]
```

which is in turn a wrapper around

```
Future[Either[Error, Option[A]]]
```

Therefore,

```
OptionT[EitherT[Future, Error, ?], User](
  EitherT[Future, Error, Option[User]](retrieveUser(oldEmail))
)
```

should typecheck (with `the non/kind-projector`), and with `-Ypartial-unification` the types should also be inferred automatically, so you could try to use

```
OptionT(EitherT(retrieveUser(oldEmail))
```

inside the for-comprehensions.